# Repeating row values for unique ID in SSRS report

Tags: reporting-services, count, group-by, ssrs-2008, distinct

Please take a look at below report(highlighted values are repeating for some reason)

[image: Repeating Rows]

[image: Report Design]

```
Query:

SELECT DISTINCT EXSS_Year, STEN_Student_ID, EXSS_Student_ID, 
STUD_Forename_1, STUD_Surname, EXSS_Act_Grade, 
COUNT(Grade) AS Count_Grade, COUNT(CourseType)AS CountType, 
EXSS_Issued_Date, EXSS_Cand_No, EXSS_Awarding_Body, Awarding_body, 
EXSS_Provision_Code, PRPH_ML2, PRPH_ML1, Course, PRPH_Title, 
Section, EXSS_Provision_Instance, EXSS_Subject_Code, EXSJ_Description, CourseType, Grade
FROM FS_Exams_English
GROUP BY EXSS_Year, STEN_Student_ID, EXSS_Student_ID, 
STUD_Forename_1, STUD_Surname, EXSS_Act_Grade, 
EXSS_Issued_Date, EXSS_Cand_No, EXSS_Awarding_Body, 
Awarding_body, EXSS_Provision_Code, PRPH_ML2, 
PRPH_ML1, Course, PRPH_Title, Section, 
EXSS_Provision_Instance, EXSS_Subject_Code, 
EXSJ_Description, CourseType, Grade
ORDER BY STEN_Student_ID
```

Sample data for Keelan Shelly:

```
Forename Surname Count_Grade CountType  Section Course  PRPH_Title                        EXSJ_Description                        CourseType    Grade
Keelan  Shelly   0           0        14-16    27448/A01 English E3 FS (14-16) (Pearson)    E3 ENGLISH FUNCTIONAL SKILLS WRITING NULL          NULL
Keelan  Shelly   0           1        CSTR     27239/A01  English L1 FS (for CSTR) (CG)     FUNCTIONAL SKILLS ENGLISH           Overall        NULL
Keelan  Shelly   0           1        14-16    27448/A01 English E3 FS (14-16) (Pearson)    E3 ENGLISH FUNTIONAL SKILLS READING Reading        NULL
```

let me know how can I avoid this.

Comment: That's confusing. You have a `distinct` **and** a `group by` clause in your query. Either or I'd say. So why don't you remove the `distinct` from your query since you have an aggregate function such as `COUNT()` in your query.

Comment: Ralph - I just removed DISTINCT and refreshed the report but there is still no change..I see duplicates...

Comment: Neither `count(Grade) as Count_Grade,` nor `count(CourseType) as CountType,` seem to be in this report. Are you sure that this report is merely it's aggregation and not yet the drill-down details to that report? Try running the query in SSMS and compare the results to the report yourself.

Comment: Can you show the data from the query for one of the duplicating rows (like Keelan)? My guess would be that the **Grade** is different (causing the duplicates) but the data on the report is 0 so it doesn;t seem right either.

Comment: I removed Details group and not seeing any duplicates now...

Comment: @Hannover - Please see above for sampl data

Answer (score 1):

I would copy the results from the above query into Excel. 
Examine the data closely for the students that are duplicating. 
The data in one of the columns is not exactly the same for the
students that are duplicating.
It is hard to say which column is causing the duplication without actually
seeing the data.

Hope this helps, 
Mark 
http://sqlreports.wordpress.com/